# How do I set multiple attributes to request in a servlet and then read them on JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request

> I am new to JSP. Have tried a lot of things to no avail. Please help me know what can be the possible problem in this code?

- Servlet Code

  request.setAttribute("list", list);
  request.setAttribute("rows",totalRows);
  request.getRequestDispatcher("sample.jsp").forward(request, response);

> Here, list is a collection of a custom datatype and totalRows holds an integer number. I am trying to set these attributes to the request so as to be able to manipulate them on my JSP, sample.jsp:

- Sample.jsp

  List rulesList = (List) request.getAttribute("list");
  request.setAttribute("rulesList", rulesList);

  String rowCount=(String)request.getAttribute("rows");
  request.setAttribute("rowCount",rowCount);

> I am unable to fetch the rowCount on JSP . rulesList works fine. Please help.

Comment: Why do you want to again set attribute in jsp file?Are there any errors thrown in server console when rows attribute is fetched?

Comment: No, there are no issues I am doing that because I am storing list/rows in new variables on JSP, so now in order to access these , rulesList and rowCount need to be set to the request right?

Comment: So do both rowCount and request.getAttribute("rows") give u blank stuff?

Comment: yes, its throwing a null pointer exception always

Comment: This should work Integer.valueOf((String)request.getAttribute("rows"));

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `.toString();` like.... `String rowCount=request.getAttribute("rows").toString();`

and for list you can refer bellow sample code :-

```
List<String> result = (List) request.getAttribute("redultList");
```